# Wildcard SSL in IIS 7 showing warning message

Tags: iis, ssl, wildcard, windows-server-2008-r2

I've read all the other threads here on SO regarding this and have even tried this [walkthrough](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html) to no avail.

I have a wildcard SSL installed on my 2008R2/IIS7 box. I have it bound to it's own IP address and I only have 1 site that's using it. The site sub-domain is in this format - sub.sub.sub.tld.tld. So my wildcard is the *.tld.tld.

The site comes up fine in HTTPS but I get the warning that reads like this:

> You attempted to reach sub.sub.sub.tld.tld, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.tld.tld. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of sub.sub.sub.tld.tld.

I'm at a loss on why this is happening as everything I've read and done should work and I should not be seeing the SSL warning since I have a wildcard SSL cert.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer and confirmed it by reading this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/what-certificates-are-needed-for-multi-level-subdomains). Seems that my *.domain SSL cert only works with 1 level of subdomains due to [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818).

> Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

So my solution is either get a SAN type of SSL Cert or reduce my subdomains to just 1 (which I did).